# Why does a childClass call its parentClass functions as well as their own?

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance, instantiation, overriding

I started getting the hang of inheritance in Perl/Moose, but I'm starting to run into some rough spots.

For example, the build order of inherited objects seems to make sense, but inheritance  doesn't seem to work how I expect--

If my baseClass calls BUILD all subClasses will call their BUILD as well as the baseClass' BUILD, but this isnt limited to the moosey BUILD function.

If I define a function init() in the baseClass, and call itfrom the baseClass BUILD, the subClasses init() gets called instead of the baseClass' init()

o_O

Assume for brevity sake that we have the follow object constructs:

```
BaseClass
    ::BUILD --> call init()
    ::init  --> do BaseStuff 

ChildClass extends BaseClass
    ::BUILD --> call init()
    ::init  --> do ChildStuff
```

Now instantiate the childClass

```
my $child = ChildClass->new();
```

The resulting call order from new() looks like this to me based on my debug output

```
BaseClass->BUILD()
BaseClass->init() <--- this calls ChildClass::init
ChildClass->BUILD()
ChildClass->init() <--- this calls ChildClass::init too!
```

I get that they both call BUILD a la Moose. Fine. I guess I'm misunderstanding why baseClass doesn't call it's own baseClass::init in this case, or alternatively why childClass doesnt just call its own childClass::BUILD.

**Do I need to specifically "override" these functions with the Moose "override" function modifier?**

Then if i throw BUILDARGS in the mix, it gets even more fun, because the question is who gets the arguments passed into new() and what if the baseClass has roles associated with it?

```
BaseClass (has role CanSee and has seesWith() attribute)
BaseClass (has role NameTag and has name() attribute)
ChildClass (has role FavoriteColor and has color() attribute)

my $child = ChildClass->new( name => 'Jane', seesWith => 'eyes', color => 'red');
```

then

```
ChildClass
        ::BUILDARGS --> 
             ($orig,$class,$args) = @_;
             return $class->$orig(@_);
```

Which is $class in this case??

Don't tell me I have to override BUILDARGS... lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a BUILD function in each class a bit like

```
sub BUILD {
    my $self = shift;
    ...
    $self->init();
    ...
}
```

Moose treats BUILD differently that Perl normally treats method calls. When you call init in your BUILD methods Perl will use it's normal method resolution and find the child's init method as it masks the parent's init method. The child's method can then call the parents with `$self->SUPER::init()`, Moose's 'override' modifier and `super()` is just modified way to use `SUPER::`.

If you only call init in your parent class's BUILD method you can use any of the standard Moose method modifiers like 'before', 'after', 'around', or 'override' to control when the child class's init is called relative to the parent's init.

If on the other hand you want each class's init to be called when that class's build is run you can specifically ask Perl to skip the standard method lookup and use a specified class's method:

```
package ParentClass;

sub BUILD {
    my $self = shift;
    ...
    $self->ParentClass::init();
    ...
}

package ChildClass;

sub BUILD {
    my $self = shift;
    ...
    $self->ChildClass::init();
    ...
}
```